# Connect Symfony/Doctrine to MS SQL Server

Tags: php, sql-server, symfony, doctrine

I need to connect my symfony project to a SQL Server database. I have some probleme when using doctrine. The error I get is :

> An exception occurred in the driver: SQLSTATE [28000, 18456]: [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server][SQL Server]Échec de l'ouverture de session de l'utilisateur 'voipsync'.

Here is part of my doctrine.yaml config file :

> ```
>         sqlserver:
>             #url: 'sqlsrv://voipsync:voipsync@[MY SERVER]\VIRTUALIA:1433/VirtualiaRh'
>             driver: 'sqlsrv'
>             user: voipsync
>             password: voipsync
>             host: [MY SERVER]\VIRTUALIA
>             port: 1433
>             dbname: VirtualiaRh
>             charset: UTF-8
>             server_version: '13'
> ```

For information, I have tested the connexion in direct PHP without using doctrine, it works perfectly. I must be missing something in the Doctrine config.

My setup : symfony serve on Windows 10, versions are Symfony V5.4.8 / Doctrine DBAL 3.3.6 / MS SQL Server 2016

Thanks in advance for your help

Comment: Well it's a user logon failure, so at least it's connecting! :) If you have access to the target SQL Server then check its ERRORLOG for the 18456 error messages, take note of the `State` number reported in them and consult [MSSQLSERVER_18456](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/errors-events/mssqlserver-18456-database-engine-error) to determine the actual cause of the login issue.

Comment: Thank you for your help. I found the errorlog of my sqlserver and the state number of the error is 5. This means "User ID is not valid." but the user exists, I can use it in the management studio. I am far from beeing an sqlserver expert, maybe I missed something when creating the user.

Comment: Is `voipsync` a Windows or Active Directory account?

Comment: Neither Windows nor AD account, I set it in SQL Server Authentication mode.